# How can I use \linebreak inside a node, in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my code, which doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node {start\linebreak{}stop};
\end{document}
```

The `\linebreak` command doesn't work. In order to make it working I have to say `\node[text width=5em]..`. Is there any other method to make it working, without explicit specification of the node text width?

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates, do not downvote.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm not going to use `\nodepart`, I just want to use `\linebreak`. I have many lines in the node, much more than `\nodepart` allows (up to 4).

Comment: Related: [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671)

Comment: The question that has been marked as duplicate is three years older than this one. In good spirit of this site, I suggest to mark the newer one a duplicate of this one, which gives a simple answer to a simple problem.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the re-open vote, so I will refrain from voting. But note that the question this question is currently linked to as a duplicate has a very thorough answer that very well includes the answer given here. It might not be as short or concise as the one from here, but it gives different approaches and some more explanation.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

There is a much simpler and more elegant solution! From the TikZ manual § 17.4.3 Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text:

```
\node[draw, align=left] {This is a\\demonstration.};
```

Key here is that you must use the `align` option, with the parameter that you want.

Comment: So many "random" details like this is the main drawback of latex. The language should be intelligent/flexible enough not to need an instruction of how to align extra lines.

Comment: @luchonacho - completely agree! There was a hack with `text width` to force line breaking, but it's so inflexible (and it was the first advice I've got). Why couldn't it work by default? And I read it's still a "side effect" of some change, that it even works at all.

Answer (score 31):

You could use a single-column `tabular` to achieve line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node {\begin{tabular}{l}
    start \\
    another \\ 
    stop
\end{tabular}};
\end{document}
```

Also macros like `\shortstack{start\\another\\stop}` are useful. I also always add a `\strut` in every line to ensure a constant line skip.

Comment: +1 for `\shortstack{start\\another\\stop}`. Works fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can also put a \parbox around your node text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node {\parbox{\widthof{another}}{
    start \\
    another \\ 
    stop}};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get several lines in a node by using `rectangle split` (of the TikZ library `shapes`) which draws a split rectangle. Set `rectangle split parts` to the number of lines you want and use `\nodepart` to switch to the next line as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw ellipse (2cm and 1cm) node [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2]{%
  First line
  \nodepart{second}
  second line%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code]

Answer (score 0):

```
\def\mynode#{\vtop \bgroup \hsize 0pt \parindent 0pt 
        \rightskip = 0pt minus \maxdimen \let\next=}
\tikz \node {\mynode{start\linebreak stop}};
```

Comment: Worked only partially for me.  By using \mynode I get a node with the correct height but the node width seems to be 0.