# Getting new line in title

Tags: titles, tikzposter

How do I make the title of this document break up and center-justify? \ doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Simple}

\title{This is a very long title that I would like to break up and center-justify} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `beamerposter` instead, but that's just preference. I anticipate this is linked to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31096/17423.

Comment: Why beamerposter?

Comment: Always seemed more stable / consistent to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `\parbox`

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Simple}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a very long title that I would like to break up and center-justify}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To break the line, `\\` would be enough. To break it nicely, you may need to specify some vertical space, `\\[1ex]`. To get it center-justified, I would recommend not to hack the `\title` command, but either find a theme that better suits your needs, or just abandon `\maketitle` to create a layout of your own with a `center` environment.

Comment: \\ doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the \linebreak command. You can optionally add a number (0-4) to this, i.e.~\linebreak[3]. The higher the number, the more insistent the command.

Comment: Unfortunately \linebreak doesn't seem to work.