# Writing latex codes on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, latexit

Is it possible to write `LaTeX` codes on `tikz`? Let me clarify this with an example: i want to create the unit circle (this part is done) with a separated text with latex code with stuff like `$\sin²+\cos²=1$ or $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$` combined with text to explain all that, at the right of the unit circle, i think that it is using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Unit circle drawing part

%Text
\node[right] (1,0) {the latex code}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

BUT, when i post the `LaTeX` code with the `$\cos²+\sin²=1$` etc, it does not form a different line or space. How can i create new lines if all this is possible? I've tried with the thing above, using `double \` for new line or `$$code$$` for new line but it does not work either. Help?

this is the code

,tex

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\filldraw[fill=green!20,draw=green!50!black] (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm) arc
(0:30:3mm) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) coordinate (y axis);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[very thick,red]
(30:1cm) -- node[anchor=east,fill=white] {$\sin \alpha$} (30:1cm |- x axis);
\draw[very thick,blue]
(30:1cm |- x axis) -- node[below=2pt,fill=white] {$\cos \alpha$} (0,0);
\draw[very thick,orange] (1,0) -- node [right=1pt,fill=white]
{$\tan \alpha \color{black}=
\frac{{\color{red}\sin \alpha}}{\color{blue}\cos \alpha}$}
(intersection of 0,0--30:1cm and 1,0--1,1) coordinate (t);
\draw (0,0) -- (t);
\filldraw (15:2mm) node[green!50!black] {$\alpha$};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {-1, -0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 1}
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-1, -0.5/-\frac{1}{2}, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1}
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east,fill=white] {$\ytext$};
\node[draw, align=right] at (2.7,0) {The $\color{green}\text{angle }\alpha$\\ is $30^{\circ}$ in the example  ($\frac{\pi}{6}$ in radians). \\ The $\color{red}{\text{sine of }\alpha}$ , which is the height\\ of the red line is\\  ${\color{red}{\sin \alpha}}=\frac12$ \\ By the Pythagoream Theorem,\\ we have \\ ${\color{blue}\cos^2 \alpha}+{\color{red}\sin^2 \alpha}=1$. \\ Thus the length of the blue line, \\ which is the$\color{blue}{\text{cosine of }\alpha}$,\\ must be\\ ${\color{blue}\cos \alpha}=\sqrt{1-\frac14}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$\\ This shows that $\color{yellow}{\tan \alpha}$, \\ which is the height of the orange line is \\  ${\color{yellow}{\tan \alpha}}=\frac{{\color{red}{\sin \alpha}}}{\color{blue}{\cos \alpha}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$}; \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Partial answer: line breaks in TikZ nodes is answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31096/).

Comment: could you upload the code showing the problem

Comment: yes but it has 1700 characters and it does not let me :(

Comment: Did you try posting the code in a comment? Don't do that, you can edit your question, and add the code in the question. There should be an *edit* link above the comments. The general answer to line breaking in TikZ nodes is however found in the link posted by snwflk, so please look at that if you haven't already.

Comment: i did looked at that but i don't understand how it is related to what i want, let me edit the code then

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. In your current code, as you've shown, you have `align=right` in the options of the last node, so line breaks with ```\\``` work just fine. After making it a bit smaller, your diagram looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwcLt.png What do you get, and what are you after?

Comment: Yeah, i agree that it does make a new line because this question is kinda outdated, should have reedited it, i have indeed gotten to make a new line, BUT the $$ does not work still, as what i want is to use double $ to make it centered

Comment: First of all: don't use `$$ .. $$`, but `\[ .. \]`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to You need to set `text width=5cm` (or some other suitable length) in the node options. TeX needs to know the width of the paragraph in order to use displayed math.

Comment: Wait so you mean to add \node[draw, align=right, text width=5cm] to be able to use ``\[ code \]``?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay thank you so infinitely much!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There are at least two possibilities.  The first is the one you have been trying, the desired text being the content of a `node`.
The second would use the `minipage` environment having the drawing on the left and the text on the right.

I followed the first solution sticking to your code, but changed the angle for clarity reasons.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[calc, math]

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{ real \a; \a=60; }
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5, every node/.style={scale=.9}]
  \draw[step=.5, gray!80!blue!40, very thin] (-1.4, -1.4) grid (1.4, 1.4);
  %% axes
  \draw[gray, thin, ->] (-1.5, 0) -- (1.5, 0) coordinate (x axis);
  \draw[gray, thin, ->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) coordinate (y axis);
  \foreach \x/\pos/\xtext in {-1/below left/-1,
    -.5/below left/-\frac{1}{2}, 1/below right/1}{%
    \draw[thick] (\x , 1pt) -- ++(0, -2pt) node[\pos] {$\xtext$};
  }
  \foreach \y/\pos/\ytext in {-1/below left/-1,
    .5/above left/\frac{1}{2}, 1/above left/1}{%
    \draw[thick] (1pt, \y) -- ++(-2pt, 0) node[\pos] {$\ytext$};
  }

  %% circle and trigonometry
  \draw[thin] (0, 0) circle (1);
  \filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20]
  (0, 0) -- (.3, 0) arc (0: \a: .3)
  node[pos=.5, anchor=south west, green!50!black, inner sep=2pt]
  {$\alpha$} -- cycle;
  
  \draw[very thick, red]
  (\a:1) -- (\a:1 |- x axis) node[pos=.5, anchor=west] {$\sin\alpha$} ;
  \draw[very thick, blue]
  (0, 0) -- (\a:1 |- x axis) node[pos=.5, anchor=north] {$\cos\alpha$};
  \draw[thick]
  (0, 0) -- (intersection of 0, 0--\a:1 and 1, 0--1, 1) coordinate (T);
  \draw[very thick, magenta]
  (1, 0) -- (T) node [pos=.5, anchor=west] {$\tan\alpha \color{black}=
    \frac{{\color{red}\sin\alpha}}{\color{blue}\cos\alpha}$};

  \path (2, .9)
  node[anchor=north west, align=left, text width=6.1cm] 
  {The {\color{green!50!black}angle} $\alpha$ is $60^{\circ}$ in the
    example ($\frac{\pi}{3}$ in radians).  \\
    The {\color{blue}cosine of} $\alpha$, which is the length of the
    blue line, is ${\color{blue}\cos\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}$. \\
    By Pythagoras' Theorem,
    ${\color{blue}\cos^2\alpha}+{\color{red}\sin^2\alpha}=1$.  Thus the
    length of the red line, which is {\color{red}sine of} $\alpha$,
    equals
    ${\color{red}\sin\alpha}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. \\
    Hence $\color{magenta}\tan\alpha$,  which is the length of the
    magenta line, equals  
    $\frac{\color{red}\sin\alpha}{\color{blue}\cos\alpha}=\sqrt{3}$.
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```