# TikZ "timeline" library - how to format text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

I would appreciate if someone could answer a few questions of mine regarding TikZ library "`timeline`" (source code is here: https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline).
Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={},timeline width=25]
 \timeline[custom interval=true]{September 2021, October 2021, November 2021, December 2021, January 2022}
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=2cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.5,involvement degree=2.5cm}
\end{phases}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={\textbf{Submission of the Grant Appliction}},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.280,direction=320:3cm,text={\textbf{The Team of Skilled Researchers will have been assembled.}},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot of the output:[image]

**I have following questions:**

1. How can I add a line break to the text in the milestone? Some annotations are too long for one line, so I would like to split them into two lines.
2. Is it possible to change distance between the left edge of the black timeline and the word "September"?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding \\? If that does not work, since it is TikZ based, I'd say try setting up the node alignment key (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31100/81905) and then linebreaking.

Comment: @Guilherme Zanotelli  -- yes, I have tried both \\ and \linebreak. Neither works, unfortunately. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add options `text width` and `align` into `text options`. It seems that they are remembered in following uses, but you can insert new ones.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={},timeline width=25]
 \timeline[custom interval=true]{September 2021, October 2021, November 2021, December 2021, January 2022}
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=2cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.5,involvement degree=2.5cm}
\end{phases}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={\textbf{Submission of the Grant Application}},text options={above, text width=2cm, align=center}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.280,direction=320:3cm,text={\textbf{The Team of Skilled Researchers will have been assembled.}},text options={below, text width=4cm, align=left}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a parbox I guess

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={},timeline width=25]
 \timeline[custom interval=true]{September 2021, October 2021, November 2021, December 2021, January 2022}
\begin{phases}
\initialphase{involvement degree=2cm}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.5,involvement degree=2.5cm}
\end{phases}
\addmilestone{at=phase-0.90,direction=90:1cm,text={\textbf{Submission of the Grant Appliction}},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.280,direction=320:3cm,text={\parbox{50mm}{\raggedright\textbf{The Team of Skilled\\Researchers will have\\been assembled.}}},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]